# Persistent error logging into physics.stackexchange.com with OpenID (Unable to log in with your OpenID provider)

Tags: support, login, openid

OS - Windows 7
Browser - Firefox v26.0

For the past few days I have been unable to log into physics.stackexchange.com using OpenID. The error I get is below. Strangely, I can log in by browsing to the root site stackexchange.com and using OpenID. Then I can go to physics.stackexchange.com and get logged in automatically because I was already logged into the root site.

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> The openid.return_to parameter
>   (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=c15344d4-17e8-49a4-a903-a295ec4a5128&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F6605b47a-8e5f-40af-8d04-e838c8675845)
>   does not match the actual URL
>   (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=c15344d4-17e8-49a4-a903-a295ec4a5128&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F6605b47a-8e5f-40af-8d04-e838c8675845&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F6605b47a-8e5f-40af-8d04-e838c8675845&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fuser%2F6605b47a-8e5f-40af-8d04-e838c8675845&openid.sig=C1VsVB5URdaZprZo0tRqzDwgmFSwk8kVDxM7mAW8lEw%3D&openid.signed=claimed_id%2Cidentity%2Cassoc_handle%2Cop_endpoint%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cns.alias3%2Calias3.mode%2Calias3.type.alias1%2Calias3.value.alias1%2Calias3.type.alias2%2Calias3.value.alias2&openid.assoc_handle=1Ltb%21IAAAALcYO9mOn_QMDQzJxGqxsg6Af5QghCn_8YIfu4gxKkOZQQAAAAGFmCfvbxvG3B3afcDveMh7dJMqemvMnVxTW1EOwFaj1sT3wDW7Pi3jk0LZzSM3rNRvArAyenOrXkCm8fgPNk76&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fopenid.stackexchange.com%2Fopenid%2Fprovider&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fphysics.stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2Fauthenticate%2F%3Fs%3Dc15344d4-17e8-49a4-a903-a295ec4a5128%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fopenid.stackexchange.com%252Fuser%252F6605b47a-8e5f-40af-8d04-e838c8675845&openid.response_nonce=2014-01-08T19%3A15%3A35ZnevwToP9&openid.mode=id_res&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.alias3=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.alias3.mode=fetch_response&openid.alias3.type.alias1=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.alias3.value.alias1=gilg%40stanford.edu&openid.alias3.type.alias2=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson&openid.alias3.value.alias2=Isopycnal%20Oscillation)
>   the request was made with.

Comment: That's...odd. We can assume a team member will read this soon and they may be able to comment.

Comment: This probably has to do with the https move

Comment: Filling out the details - your browser, OS, OpenID provider, etc. - will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty How do I find out my OpenID provider?

Comment: It is normally the Google, Yahoo or Facebook service you used when signing up. Try signing up to some oth SE site to jog your memory if you can't remember which one you used.

Comment: Are you using the https anywhere browser extension? It looks like you're trying to access SE using SSL which is currently not supported and leads to this particular error message, try disabling any extensions that force the use of SSL.

Comment: @MadScientist That was it. You can add it as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4901/23119) related/?